# Email php script won't send emails

Tags: php, html, email, html-email

I am having trouble with getting the mail php script to work, I probably dont understand why because I already looked it up on the internet, but I do not find a correct solution ( kinda new to this )

If I run the script it is always entering to the last if then else with something went wrong please try again.

Here are the scripts:

```
<?php


 $siteOwnersEmail = 'test@gmail.be';


if($_POST) {

$name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactName']));
$email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactEmail']));
$subject = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactSubject']));
$contact_message = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactMessage']));

// Check Name
if (strlen($name) < 2) {
    $error['name'] = "Please enter your name.";
}
// Check Email
if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9&\'\.\-_\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z0-9\-]+\.)*+[a-z]{2}/is', $email)) {
    $error['email'] = "Please enter a valid email address.";
}
// Check Message
if (strlen($contact_message) < 15) {
    $error['message'] = "Please enter your message. It should have at least 15 characters.";
}
// Subject
if ($subject == '') { $subject = "Contact Form Submission"; }


// Set Message
$message .= "Email from: " . $name . "<br />";
$message .= "Email address: " . $email . "<br />";
$message .= "Message: <br />";
$message .= $contact_message;
$message .= "<br /> ----- <br /> This email was sent from your site's contact form. <br />";

// Set From: header
$from =  $name . " <" . $email . ">";

// Email Headers
$headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


 if (isset($error)) {

    $response = (isset($error['name'])) ? $error['name'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
    $response .= (isset($error['email'])) ? $error['email'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
    $response .= (isset($error['message'])) ? $error['message'] . "<br />" : null;

    echo $response;


} # end if - there was a validation error
else {


  ini_set("sendmail_from", $siteOwnersEmail); // for windows server
  $mail = mail($siteOwnersEmail, $subject, $message, $headers);

    if ($mail) { echo "OK"; }
  else { echo "Something went wrong. Please try again."; }

} # end if - no validation error

}

}

?>
```

And last but not least the form for submitting

```
<form name="contactForm" id="contactForm"  action="inc/sendEmail.php" method="post" >
                <fieldset>

                <div class="form-field">
                    <input name="contactName" type="text" id="contactName" placeholder="Naam" value="" minlength="2" required="" aria-required="true" class="full-width">
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <input name="contactEmail" type="email" id="contactEmail" placeholder="Email" value="" required="" aria-required="true" class="full-width">
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <input name="contactSubject" type="text" id="contactSubject" placeholder="Onderwerp" value="" class="full-width">
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <textarea name="contactMessage" id="contactMessage" placeholder="Uw vraag" rows="10" cols="50" required="" aria-required="true" class="full-width"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <button class="full-width btn--primary">Submit</button>
                    <div class="submit-loader">
                        <div class="text-loader">Sending...</div>
                        <div class="s-loader">
                            <div class="bounce1"></div>
                            <div class="bounce2"></div>
                            <div class="bounce3"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

Comment: Could you provide some context on the error you're getting back?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to send mail it working

```
    <?php
$malil = 'example@example.com';
$to = $malil;

$subject = "Your order has been placed.";

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' . "\r\n";   

$headers .= "From: example@example.com" . "\r\n" ;
/* $headers .= "Cc:reservations@bookingsmaker.com,bookingsmakerdotcom@gmail.com,bookingsmakerworld@gmail.com "."\r\n";
*/
$headers .="Cc:example@example.com,example@example.in";

////////////////***********Html format*****************//////////////////
$htmlContent = 'Content';

$result=mail($to,$subject,$htmlContent,$headers);
  if($result){
      echo 'mail Send';
  }else{
      echo 'Mail not send';
  }
  ?>
```